# Sort a Multi-D Array by Sub-Array Count

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with sorting an array.

I have an array for my categories like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want sort this array by `count(subcategory)` like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => category
            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
            [subcategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => category - first
                            [url] => http//mycategoryurl
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Please help me sort this array like in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) function with a callback:

```
$arr = array(); // your array
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return count($a['subcategory']) < $count($b['subcategory'])? -1 : 1; });
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: it is working but i want sorting be desc. now it is acs. thanks

Comment: i had change "<" to ">". now it is Ok. thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function like so:

```
usort($arrayToSort, function($a, $b){
    $aCount = count($a['subcategory']);
    $bCount = count($b['subcategory']);
    if ($aCount  == $bCount) {
        return 0;
    }

    //flip the '>' to '<' for ascending sort. It is set to do descending 
    return ($aCount > $bCount) ? -1 : 1;

});
```